# jQuery post to PHP not returning full result

Tags: jquery

I have tried to find a solution, but coming up blank.
My page requires a swapout of information when a link is selected.
Basicaly you select an item of choice, then the main div is swaped out with a form and data regarding your selection.

I already have a functioning page setup for this, but as it is all in PHP, the page reloads completely each time. This is not good for some selections as there is a full refresh of the link section as well ( which can be quite long depending on member ). So reload time can be a little long on some accounts, that is why I am opting for the jQuery swapout.

This is my jQuery script.

```
        function swapContent(cv) {
        $("#input").html('<img src="28.gif"/>').show();
             var url = "scripts/run.php";
             $.post(url, {contentVar: cv} ,function(data) {
             $("#input").html(data).show();
              });
         }
```

PHP is simple "echo" return of value.

```
if ($contentVar == true) {
echo $resultLoad;
}
```

**$resultLoad;** is the completed variable that is created in the PHP script.
All looks good and seems to work on most things, but I am having a little problem with the "echo" outputing all its info.

If I add a second "echo", befor or after the if statement ( or even a second inside it as well ), the first echo will always have half the info displayed and the rest display fine.

It is not a timing isue as I have tried timers in jQuery and PHP to allow data completion with no affect.

If you want to see it for yourself, you can go to the [test page](http://www.youtubetutsite.com/thumb_selectTEST.php) ( but you need to be a loggedIn member with a YouTube account with uploads in it ) 
Dont worry.... Free site :)

But if you dont have one, then here is a [screen capture](http://www.youtubetutsite.com/graphics/screenCap.jpg) for example.

=======================================================================

**EDIT:**

@Rusty Jeans ( and anyone else ) I have a large script that runs in PHP.
In PHP, I have a function that reads a YouTube streem for a given members account.
I then pars out the reletive info that is required which is suplied in an SXML format from the YT server. I then do a check to see if I have that particular video already in the system. 
All this works fine. Problem comes from the last part that writes out a HTML form and displays it.

```
          include_once "dropdown_java.php";


          $resultLoad = $dropdown_java.'
          <table width="455" border="0">
           <tr>
            <td>
            <p><div class="thumbnail"><a href="' . $href . '\" target="_blank">
              <img src="' . $thumb . '" width="120" height="90" /></a></div></p>
              <p><b><u>VideoId:</u></b><br /> ' . $vid . '</p>
                 <p><b><u>Video Title:</u></b><br /> ' . $vidtitle . '</p> <p><b><u>Video Discription:</u></b><br /> ' . $vidDiscript . '</p>
             </td>
                 </tr>
                </table>   

                  <form action="php_uploader.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myform" id="dataInput">
              <span class="alignRt"><b><u>Area Of Interest:</u></b><br />
                <select name="Area_Of_Interest" size="1" id="Area_Of_Interest"
                    onchange="setOptions(document.myform.Area_Of_Interest.options[document.myform.Area_Of_Interest.selectedIndex].value);">
                        '.$first_option_dropdown.'
                    </select><br /><br />
            <span class="alignRt"><b><u>Category:</u></b><br />
                    <select name="Category" id="Category" size="1">
                    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                </select>

         </span></p>


               <p><span class="alignRt"><b><u>Difficulty:</u></b>
               <input name="Difficulty" type="text" class="formFields" id="Difficulty" size="1" maxlength="1" />
               <font size="-1" >Difficulty out of 5 [ 1: Easy - 5: Hard ]    </font></span>
          <p>
             </p><font size="-1" >Please supply a zip file with the learning material for the tutorial</p></font>

              <font size="2"><b>Choose your file here: </b></font><a href="#" onclick="MM_popupMsg(\'Only .zip format will be uploaded.\rAnything else will be converted to a .zip and be unreadable.\')">
         <font size="1" style="cursor: help" color="#00CCFF"><b>(?)</b></font></a>
    <input name="zipFile" type="file" class="formFields" id="zipFile" style="border-style: none; color: white; background-color: #000; border-style: solid; border-color: white; border-width: 1px;"/><br /><br />
       <br />
                      <input name="Submit3" type="submit" onclick="MM_validateForm(\'youtube\',\'\',\'R\',\'Video_Title\',\'\',\'R\',\'VideoID\',\'\',\'R\',\'Video_Discription\',\'\',\'R\',\'Area_Of_Interest\',\'\',\'R\',\'Category\',\'\',\'R\',\'Difficulty\',\'\',\'RinRange1:5\');
           return document.MM_returnValue" value="Submit Form" /></form>
          </p>';
```

If you notice as well, I have a javascript in the form for the dropdown lists.

For some reason the first table and the "dropdown java" chunck is omited in the first pass of the echo's. I did join them as well as a test, but still NO.

===============================================================

UPDATE :

==========

After some research and playing around, I have found out two things.
Firstly, it seems that the javascript in the php is the cause some how. Might be wrong, but does seem that way. ( my untrained eye )

Secondly, I have found that it works on GoogleChroma and FireFox just fine. Only IE is acting up. I am testing on IE8.

I hope that someone can help with this or has had a similar problem in the past that was solved.

Comment: The screenshot is quite useless, we can't know what it should contain. Please post example of what you send from PHP vs. what you get in the AJAX callback.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard The screencapture has both echo's showing. The submit button is the end of the code, so the "picture" onwords is a FULL echo of info.

Comment: @genesis It is a legal requirement to put that there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the jQuery is interpreting it incorrectly? Try adding the `"html"` type to your `$.post()`:

```
function swapContent (cv) {
    $("#input").html('<img src="28.gif"/>').show();
    var url = "scripts/run.php";
    $.post(url, {contentVar: cv}, function (data) {
        $("#input").html(data).show();
    }, "html");
}
```

There is also a shorthand method specifically for what you're doing, [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
$("#input").load("scripts/run.php?contentVar=" + cv).show();
```

You'll have to access `$_GET['contentVar']` instead of `$_POST['contentVar']` in your PHP.

Comment: Thanks and I have tried both of your scripts. As scripts go, they work as well as each other, but still get the same problem tho. I am not familiar with jQuery and all of its foibles, but am thinking that it might be something to do with jQuery itself. What I do not know.

Comment: Can you provide what your PHP is returning versus what you're getting back via the `.post()`? That might be helpful in figuring out if there's something in your content that's causing a problem. Maybe your returned html isn't valid or something like that.